# How to return a promise of a map object related to key of Mapper

Tags: typescript

I need to define a type definition of a function like this:

```js
type ContentMap = {
   typeOne: TypeOne;
   typeTwo: TypeTwo;
   typeThree: TypeThree;
}

const getContent = <T extends Array<keyof ContentMap>>(inputs: T) => Promise<{[p in keyof T]: T[p]}>



--- expectation ----

type ContentMap = {
   one: number,
   two: string,
   three: { name: string }
}


getContent(['one', 'two']) => Promise<{ 'one': number, 'two': string }>
```

## **More Information**

we have something similar in Promise.all type definition (which the return type is related to the input types)

```js
all<T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(values: T): Promise<{ -readonly [P in keyof T]: Awaited<T[P]> }>;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
const getContent: <Key extends keyof ContentMap>(keys: Key[]) => Promise<Pick<ContentMap, Key>>;
```

now I can say:

```js
getContent(["one", "two"])
    .then((result) => {
        // the result type is { "one": number, "two": string }
    })
```